# Need to replicate users between two sites in wordpress Multisite installation

Tags: database, wordpress, multisite

It was suggested in my earlier question that I should work with multisite. Little background:

Why we chose Multisite? 
We have users registered on site1 but wanted them to be able to share their content on site2, so we installed mutisite assuming that our users will be able to access site2 without registering with us again.

Here is what we thought would happen:
If a user is registered at mysite.com then user can just visit mysite/site2 and would just need to login (not create an account again) or be logged in automatically.

Here is what happens:
A test user is able to access both the websites but cant access site2 properly. Meaning, user gets some 404 on some pages in site2.( this user is registered on site1 only)

Things to note:
1. All users are registered on site1 and through dashboard, they are visible in the main site aka site1 and not site2. Site2>Dashboard>users has only those users who registered on this site separately.
Is there anyway that we can replicate users from site1 to site2?

2. A username like first.last in site1 becomes first-last in site2 URL.
3. I can be logged in as userA in site1 and userB in site2. Which is something we want to avoid.

Are these limitations normal in the multisite setup or have I missed something in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

User accounts are shared between sites, however they must be individually granted permission on each site. By default, a user created on Site1 has no privileges on site2 until added by an admin.

An admin can manually add existing users to each site, or if you want to achieve this automatically, you can use the [add_user_to_blog() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog) in your theme or plugin code to automatically add users to site2 if they have appropriate permissions on site1.

On my subdirectory-based multisite installation, sessions are shared between sites. Meaning if userA logs in to site1, then they are automatically also logged in at site2. If you are using subdomain-based multisite, then the behavior might be different but I am not sure. Maybe it can be configured so that session cookies are shared between the subdomains somehow.

Comment: thanks . Yes its a subdirectory installation and sessions are being shared by users between two sites. Adding manually is another good option now that i know the default multisite wordpress behavior.